# Why isn't my onchange function working?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby and trying to call js function onchange here but not working and not getting suitable answer.

```
= f.select :amendment_type, [['Renewal','renewal'],['Lease Amendment Agreement','Lease Amendment Agreement'],['Expansion','Expansion'],['Storage','Storage'],['Parking','Parking'],['Other(for me to fill in)','Other']], class: "amendment_type input", style: "width: 450px;", onchange: "alert('hello')"
```

Comment: Show the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` method parameters are:

> select(method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)

You've used `options` against `html_options`, so you have to replace your code with:

```
= f.select :amendment_type, [['Renewal','renewal'],['Lease Amendment Agreement','Lease Amendment Agreement'],['Expansion','Expansion'],['Storage','Storage'],['Parking','Parking'],['Other(for me to fill in)','Other']], {}, class: "amendment_type input", style: "width: 450px;", onchange: "alert('hello')"
```